# Run command in cmd.exe using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am opening cmd. I specify a path and want to run a command which is stored in createDBsQuery file which I have stored in `$createdbs` variable.

My doubt is: Can we send cd...(path) and then the command which I want to run, at the same time using PowerShell. If the above case is possible, my way of passing the arguments is correct or not?

My code:

```
$somefile = "C:\ProgramFiles\site.txt"     

$createdbs = "C:\PowerShell\createDBsQuery"

Start-Process cmd.exe -Args '/c cd C:\ProgramFiles\Infor\Tools',$createdbs -RedirectStandardOutput $somefile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell, like any shell, can execute console applications directly, synchronously, with the application's standard streams connected to PowerShell's streams.

Only ever use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) if you want to run a program *in a new window*<sup>[1]</sup>; also note that `Start-Process` is *asynchronous* by default.

The following shows you how to run your `createDbsQuery` command directly and synchronously from PowerShell, using PowerShell to temporarily change the working directory and to capture the command's output in a file:

```
$somefile = "C:\ProgramFiles\site.txt"     

$createdbs = "C:\PowerShell\createDBsQuery"

# Change to the directory required by the $createdbs script.
# and save the current directory.
Push-Location 'C:\ProgramFiles\Infor\Tools'

# Invoke the script and capture its stdout out in file $somefile
# Since the command path is stored in a variable, `& ` is needed to
# invoke it.
# Note that in Windows PowerShell `>` creates Unicode (UTF-16LE) files by default.
# In PowerShell [Core] 6+, BOM-less UTF-8 is used.
# To control the encoding, pipe to Set-Content; e.g.:
#   & $createdbs | Set-Content $someFile -Encoding Utf8
& $createdbs > $somefile

# Restore the previous directory.
Pop-Location
```

As you can see, there is no need to involve `cmd.exe` (but if `$createdbs` happens to be a *batch file*, (`*.bat`, `*.cmd`), `cmd.exe` will *implicitly* execute it), given that PowerShell, as a shell in its own right, offers the same kind of features as `cmd.exe` - and many more.

---

<sup>[1] There's also a `-NoNewWindow` option, but it is rarely needed, given that direct invocation gives you not only synchronous, same-window execution by default, but also connects the invoked program's standard output streams to PowerShell's, enabling output capturing and redirection.`-NoNewWindow` is primarily useful with `-Wait` for temporarily *troubleshooting* `Start-Process` calls meant to run in a new window, if that windows closes (too) quickly due to an error, to see what output is produced there.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In your CMD, enter "PowerShell". This should forward you into the newest version of the Windows PowerShell. This can be up to version 5.1. If you already have .NET Core installed, you can enter "Pwsh". This will enter you in the newer PowerShell version, i.e 6.2.
Your prompt should also get a 'PS [...]>' prefix.

Answer (score 0):

If it is really necessary to run cmd, while already using PowerShell, this will serve your purpose:

```
$somefile = "C:\ProgramFiles\site.txt"     

$createdbs = "C:\PowerShell\createDBsQuery"

Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/c cd C:\ProgramFiles\Infor\Tools & $createdbs" -RedirectStandardOutput $somefile
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a powershell .ps1 script file with all the necessary parameters and call it from CMD as below for example.

```
powershell -command "&{"C:\temp\script.ps1"}"
```

Comment: you are telling to put path(C:\ProgramFiles\Infor\Tools) and command (present in $createdbs which i have mentioned) in .ps1 script and then call it from power shell?

Comment: There is never a need to use `& { ... }` in a command string passed to `-command`, so `powershell -command C:\temp\script.ps1` will do. Generally, `-File` is the better choice for invoking a script file, which notably eases quoting pains if your script file path happens to contain spaces.

Comment: Yes, you can copy all the code section from your question into a script.ps1 file and run it from command prompt using the command above.

You can also check pushd and popd options in CMD to run this directly without calling PowerShell.